# PHP Zend 2 Framework show Textarea

Tags: php, zend-framework2, textarea, zend-form

I'm creating a form using Zend2 framework, and can't figure out why a simple `Textarea` is not showing up on the view (below you can see my code). I've tried the type `Text` and it shows a standard single lined text field, but got luck with `Textarea`. I've also tried a non existing type, and zend throws an exception, so it seems `Textarea` type actually exists, and I must be missing a mandatory param or something like that. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
$this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Textarea',
        'name' => 'pincodes',
        'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Pincodes (uno por línea)',
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'rows' => '10',
        'cols' => '75',
    )
));
```

---

**SOLVED**

My bad, it looks there was an intermediate layer in the project ignoring all the `Textarea` fields.

Comment: How are you displaying the form (and more specifically that element) in your view?

Comment: @TimFountain, just updated my question, it was finally a really dumb issue, but would have never found it without you making me look deeper in the project, so thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your 'rows' and 'cols' value from a string to integer (remove single quotes).

```
'attributes' = > array(
    'rows' => 10,
    'cols' => 75,
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Morgy, looked promising but doesn't work neither :(

Comment: How are you displaying this element on your view?

Answer (score 0):

I just check you code and found 2 things missing first

```
use Zend\Form\Element; 
use Zend\Form\Form;
```

Which I think you have used in you file.
Another mistake was you were missing comma in the code. use this below code.

```
$this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Textarea',
        'name' => 'pincodes',
        'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Pincodes (uno por línea)',
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'rows' => '10',
        'cols' => '75',
    ),
));
```

Good luck